# Как из js кода выполнить метод контролера

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

Имеется кнопка на вьюхе

```
bool isPayAvailable = GetPaymentButtonEnabled(int statusId);
<button id="payButton" @(!isPayAvailable ? "disabled" : string.Empty)>Оплатить</button>
```

Также есть кнопка, по которой происходит изменений параметра statusId. Оказывается, что в обработчике нажатия этой кнопки есть код, который меняет атрибут disabled для кнопки "Оплатить". Получается, что происходит дублирование кода. Вопрос тогда такой: как из JS-файла вызвать метод контроллера?

Comment: `@(!isPayAvailable ? "disabled" : string.Empty)` - вот этим же кодом устанавливается включен/выключен состояние. или я вопроса не понял

Comment: поищите в коде этой кнопки [атрибут disabled](http://htmlbook.ru/html/button/disabled) и уберите его. тогда кнопка станет доступна всегда. либо же за это отвечает код `@(...` , который, судя по всему, проверяет наличие isPayAvailable и добавляет атрибут disabled кнопке при отсутствии искомых данных

Comment: @Bald Оно устанавливается, но после нажатия другой кнопки сбрасывается. Сейчас пытаюсь найти в коде быть может есть еще места, где изменяется аттрибут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я бы создал `data` атрибут в него записал необходимый `url`, а в `javascript` получил значение из этого атрибута и выполнил необходимые действия.

---

Например:

```
<button id="customButton" data-target="@Url.Action("Метод", "Контроллер")" data-target="#content"></button>

//здесь будет выведен результат запроса 
<div id="content"></div>
```

Метод в контролере

```
public ActionResult Test(string payId)
{
    //код метода
}
```

где то в js

```
$('customBtn').on('click', function(){
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var payId = $("#payId").val().
    var completeUrl = //склеиваем в итоге может получиться что то типа
    //TestController/Test?payId=5;
    $.ajax({
        url: completeUrl,
        success: function (result) {
            $(target).html(result);
        }
    })
    });
    //дальнейшие действия
});
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что в этом случае в переменной url будет лежать результат метода контроллера? Как можно передать в метод параметры?

Comment: @AleksandrZharinov уточните какой параметр Вы хотите передать в метод, и как он получен

Comment: параметр, допустим, некий Guid. Как я вижу, в коде активно используется конструкция вида @Html.Hidden("payId", payId). А потом в JS: var payId = $("#payId").val(). Как например такую переменную в метод контроллера передать?

Comment: `@Html.Hidden("payId", payId)` как и его перегруженная версия `HiddenFor()` предназначена для создания *невидимого* пользователю поля, в данном случае туда записывается `id` записи

Comment: Да, это я понял, спасибо.